# UINavigationBar line doesn't show on parent UIViewController after being removed on the pushed UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift3, uinavigationbar

I have removed the `UINavigationBar` bottom line from a `UIViewController` that was pushed;

Everything works properly until I tap the back button, to see that the parent `UIViewController` (the one who pushed) doesn't have the bottom line as well.

The problem here is that I only want the bottom line to be removed from a specific `UIViewController` and not from all the view-stack.

Here's how I'm removing the line:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
```

Any hint?

Thank you.

Comment: I think you have to revert back the change in navigation bar when you go back to parent view controller in `viewWillAppear` method.

Comment: The thing is, how do I know the default background image?  Or how to access the defaults properties ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In method `viewWillAppear` of Parent View Controller add :

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: UIBarMetrics.default)
```

or in `viewWillDisappear` method of view controller in which you are changing the image add the same above line.

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass `UINavigationController` and change the images in the `willShowViewController` (or `didShowViewController`) delegate method like this:

```
class NavigationController: UINavigationController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        delegate = self
    }

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        if viewControllers.count > 1 {
            navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
            navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        } else {
            navigationBar.shadowImage = nil
            navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .default)
        }
    }

}
```

Depending on how you instantiate your navigation controller you have to override some other initializers als well.